# ip range whitelist error

Tags: ip, whitelist

I need to whitelist an ip range for our load testing with Loadimpact. They have given us an ip list with ranges listed as:

54.80.0.0/13 (54.80.0.0 – ﻿54.87.255.255) 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701

I'm not sure what part of the ip there to specify in our cloudflare firewall rule list.

If I enter, e.g. 54.80.0.0/13

I get the error:

An IP range (CIDR) must be a /16 or /24

How can I whitelist these?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe LoadImpact thinks /13 is too big to whitelist. A work-around may be to whitelist the network in parts:

- 54.80.0.0/16
- 54.81.0.0/16
- 54.82.0.0/16
- 54.83.0.0/16
- 54.84.0.0/16
- 54.85.0.0/16
- 54.86.0.0/16
- 54.87.0.0/16